Is there a way to parse jsonlogic rules to an sql where clause?
I want to generate a query using the react awesome query builder and then send it to the backend. The backend should then be able to parse the query to sql which should be used further. The json logic rules can be converted into Rule-Objects from the Json.Logic library using the JsonSerializer, but these objects I cannot further parse to sql.
I know there is a why to apply the rule to a given set of data, but it seems unfit for my use case, as I want to minimize the bandwidth. The frontend is build in React and the backend is a dotnet REST Api using entity framework and a MYSQL database.
I am not using the plain sql format, because of the obvious risk of sql injection.
I hope I could explain the problem. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments.
Here is a screenshot of the query Builder

Here is the json logic returned by the query builder
Just the logic part of the format

And here is the backend

Here is a screenshot from the data, that the backend gets from the frontend
The colors come from using the reSharper plugin and another coloring plugin
They are no errors ;)

I tried to research variouse sites, including this one, but seems to be nobody that wants to use json logic the way I want to.

You could use an expression builder in order to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412241/build-expression-to-filter-data-ef-core
